# Meteor.loginWithPassword returns error 404 “Method ‘login’ not found’

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

It worked when I test it on local pc, user can login/logout without any problem.
Then I deploy the app on mobile using this command:

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server myapp.herokuapp.com
```

Upon user clicks login on the mobile, Meteor.loginWithPassword returns this:

```
errorClass {error: 404, reason: "Method 'login' not found", details: undefined, message: "Method 'login' not found [404]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}
```

What could be wrong with the 'login'? Why is it not found on the mobile?
Can anyone help please.

Comment: I think you also need to specify --mobile-server which a url accessible on your mobile device, maybe if you are on the same wifi network then the ip address e.g. 192.168.1.4:3000 or whatever the address is

Comment: I did specify --mobile-server myapp.herokuapp.com, but somehow Meteor.loginWithPassword returns error 404 saying 'login' method not found

Comment: Can you put --debug and confirm what are the debug logs

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out my latest deployment to Heroku that contained accounts-password package was a bad build, therefore the app couldn't communicate to the server for a successful login. Fixed the error and re-deploy, now app is working normally. *Facepalm*